# How to show a binomial combination of two sets of values?

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I have 2 sets,

```
set1=0.05:0.05:2.5; 
set2=2.55:0.05:5;
```

I want to show all of the combinations of `set1` and `set2` in Matlab, ideally in a matrix-type format. Since `size(set1)` and `size(set2)` are both *1*-by-*50*, the dimension of the combinations matrix should be *50*-by-*50*.

Comment: You probably need two matrices as output, right? One for each member of the combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use `meshgrid` that provides all the combinations as two matrices along the grid axes.

```
set1=0.05:0.05:2.5;
set2=2.55:0.05:5;
[A,B] = meshgrid(set1,set2);
```

**A simple example:**

```
figure();
a = 1:4;
b=1:1:5;
[A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
Z = zeros(5,4);
mesh(A,B,Z,'EdgeColor','black')
axis equal;
h1 = gca;
h1.XTick = [1 2];
h1.YTick = [1 2 3];
xlabel('meshgrid Output')
```

[image]

A and B are the output coordinate arrays which include all the existing combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a cell array where each element has the pair of elements comprising the combination, you can use arrayfun:

```
[A, B] = meshgrid(set1, set2);
combs = arrayfun(@(x, y) [x y], A, B, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

If you want the output to be a 50x50x2 array, where combinations are at `combs(i, j, :)`, you can just append A and B together:

```
[A, B] = meshgrid(set1, set2);
combs = cat(3, set1, set2);
```